# JD Edwards... call C#?

Tags: c#, jdedwards

I know very little about JD Edwards. I have a client asking how to call an API we supply (as COM, C#, REST) from JD Edwards. I'm not getting much in terms of high quality answers from their tech guy... so I thought I'd ask here.

Can JD Edwards call C#?
Can JD Edwards call Java?
Can JD Edwards call a Unix scipt?

Can anyone point me towards anything useful in terms of developer/customization documentation?

Thanks!

Comment: I'll give you an upvote just for coming in contact with JDE.  Ugh.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Short answer: yes. JDE can communicate with a bunch of external objects/services/adapters.

Long answer: your options depend on what version of JDE your customer is using and what are the requirements for said communication.

Since you're mentioning that they want to call an API, I'm assuming they have a pretty recent version (say, OneWorld/EnterpriseOne product, version XE or newer) and that they need "online interface" (I mean, they will call the API from JDE and wait for it to finish processing and return something, before their JDE program continues) instead of "batch processing".

Your best option, I think, would be COM. JDE is compliant with COM. Your customer will have to know his way around JDE Interoperability, specially calling an external API using COM and GenCOM (that's how the API would be kind of packaged for JDE's usage).

Can it connect to Java? Yes. Kind of the same way it does with COM, you have to package/encapsulate the code to be consumed.

Can it use XML? Yes.

What about Adapters? Yes. MQ WebSphere, MSMQ.

Webservices? Maybe. It depends on what version of JDE is used. Recent versions do Webservices pretty well. You can provide a business function from JDE to be consumed by others and you can also consume services from others, so if your API can be used in a web service, JDE could consume it (again, depending on the version they have).

For webservices, you can use wSG (Web Services Gateway), Business Services Server and JMQ Queue/Topic for J2EE Connectivity.

Other methods available are more suitable for batch processing: EDI, OSA, z tables, table conversions.

Oracle has pretty good guides on JDE Tools (you have to search for EnterpriseOne Tools version 8.98 guides), specially for WebServices, as they are the new thing.

Comment: Do you where I can find some samples regarding this? Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Found these, they seem useful:

[Microsoft BizTalk Adapters for JD Edwards EnterpriseOne](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/biztalk/core/jd-edwards-enterpriseone-adapter)

[Microsoft BizTalk Adapters for JD Edwards OneWorld](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/biztalk/core/jd-edwards-oneworld-adapter)

[JD Edwards Interface Development](http://it.toolbox.com/blogs/integrate-my-jde/jd-edwards-interface-development-33880)

Answer (score 1):

JDE has a [WebSphere adapter](http://www-01.ibm.com/software/integration/wbiadapters/jdedwards/) that may help you bridge the gap between itself and any external applications you may have.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at LynX Business Integrator. You can write integrations in C#. Here is a link to a demo: http://m.youtube.com/watch?v=3GJjhEeHe_Q